# MailChimp API Integration with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, mailchimp

Currently I'm working on MailChimp API integration with ruby on rails.

In my application, users can create articles after creation is success I need to send the article title and content to the user mail chimp account campaigns.

For this I'm using **Hominid Gem** and fetching the campaign members from **MailChimp** account and dispatching mails from my application using action mailer in my own HTML format.

Can anyone please explain me how to send the article content in **campaign template format** through **MailChimp** account and please let me know if any such API methods available in Hominid Gem or some another gem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kalyan

Comment: This is a loaded question, so I'm just going to link the several resources you need: There are many [ways to create a campaign's content](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/what-are-the-different-ways-i-can-create-a-campaign-in-mailchimp), [including using a template](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/what-templates-do-you-have-besides-the-free-ones-i-can-download) - play with them inside the app. Once you are comfortable with that, you'll find you can do the same things using the [API's campaignCreate() method](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/1.3/campaigncreate.func.php). In the Usage section of the

Comment: Jesse, really thankfull for your reply. I think h.campaign_create method will create new campaign in the given mailchimp account, but my requirement is "sending mails(article content) to the seleted campaign list members through mailchimp account instead of my Rails application."

Comment: Right, so you create the campaign and then, depending on the type of campaign, you send it. campaignSendNow and campaignSchedule are the API methods you'll likely want to use. Hominid supports all of the API's method via method missing, so with all of this info it's time to start playing around.

Comment: Jesse, thanks for your valuable information. I played around API methods, It's working fine now.